# SQL rating to given integer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the `Rating` from this table:

```
Rating IntervalStart  IntervalEnd     
----   -------------- -----------
5       0              1
4       1              2
3       2              3
2       3              12
1       12             24
```

For example:

- if I pass `1`, output should be `5`
- if I pass `1.5`, output should be `4`

So far I have tried:

```
select * from table where 1 between IntervalStart and IntervalEnd
```

but if I pass `1`, it returns two records. I want a single row.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx.  "BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is **greater than or equal to** the value of begin_expression and **less than or equal to** the value of end_expression."

Comment: So the `IntervalEnd` is *inclusive* and the `IntervalStart` is *exclusive*?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to specify different inclusivity/exclusivity for the two ends of an interval, you cannot use `BETWEEN` - you have to specify the comparisons separately:

```
select * from table where 1 > IntervalStart and 1 <= IntervalEnd
```

Answer (score 2):

The `BETWEEN` operator is inclusive.

`WHERE x BETWEEN a AND b` equals to `a <= x <= b`

If you want to create smth like that: `a < x <= b`, you can use

`WHERE x > a AND x <= b`

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
select Rating from table where IntervalStart <= 1 AND IntervalEnd >= 1;
```

Hope so this will work for you.

Comment: This will produce exactly the same results as `1 BETWEEN IntervalStart and IntervalEnd` which the OP has in their question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know it there was some network problem due to that I have posted this answer late. and this will produce same result as require by OP.